# coding projects folder found in Trash followed by some strange timestamp on MacOs

Tags: macos, finder, monterey

I keep all my coding projects in a folder called src. It's path is: ~/src

Today I woke up to find my entire src folder along with all of its projects (usually .git repositories stored only locally) are in the Bin (trash) and I'm absolutely certain I didn't put it there.
No one else has access to my M1 Macbook Pro. I attached a picture of what I have in the Bin.

I am running MacOS Monterey 12.6 on an M1 Macbook Pro and I only run code locally from VSCode, Eclipse, JMeter etc. I am certain I didn't add those timestamps (for example src 14.05.41) myself.

Please let me know if you have any idea how/why this happened or if you know how to "Put back" everything the way it was before.

[image]

Comment: Is your original src folder still at the place you expect it to be? Does the timestamp on the zip files (the one you get with Cmd-I) give a clue?

Comment: the original src folder is completely missing from where it was before. the one marked in the attached image seems to be the latest one, but its in the Bin (trash). By pressing space key it shows it was last modified on 8th of december

Comment: If you haven't moved the directory manually, a tool/process on your Mac did. Only you know what you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer explaining the timestamps:

Deleting items via the Finder will cause the item in the Trash to have an appended timestamp if a same-named item already exists in the Trash. A quick test:

```
mkdir ~/test
cd ~/test
vim testfile.txt         # add some text
```

Delete `~/test/testfile.txt` via the Finder. It will appear in Trash as that name.

Repeat the edit / delete as above once more and you'll find the second deleted file to be timestamped as when you deleted it. The original `testfile.txt` will keep its original name in Trash.

[image]

As to what originally deleted the files, it could have been done in one of the IDEs you mention if it uses Finder APIs.